# Total number of elements

Tags: matlab

Test Context:... [x,y] = calc_barrel_pos(xpos, ypos, turret_width, barrel_length, theta, player)

Test Question: What is the total number of elements(that is individual numbers) that should be returned by the calc_barrel_pos function. (Hint: are the number of variables the same as the number of elements?)

My interpretation: The term ‘returned’ would normally mean what is outputted, thus, the value of the function, correct? Therefore, it would be x,y which are 2 different numbers
This answer is given as wrong and the indicated answer, 4, implies it is the number of variables. I don’t understand at all.

Why 4?

Comment: if you find the answer below acceptable, please click the check mark underneath where you vote on the answer

Answer (score 2):

I think the Hint is suggesting that even though there are 2 variables returned `x` & `y`, the number of elements could be greater. Since the correct answer was 4, I would guess `x` and `y` are each two element vectors. Or perhaps there are 4 elements in `x` and another 4 in `y` and they represent points on the corners of a box. It's hard to know for sure without knowing what calc_barrel_pos does.

Just to clarify the difference between elements and variables, in the line `x=[1 3];` x is one variable, but it has 2 elements.